# How to move character in direction of view in godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I have a camera freely rotating around the character, but I can't figure out how to make the movement relative to the gaze. I tried like this

```
extends CharacterBody3D

var speed = 0
var direction = Vector3()

func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("forward"):
        speed = 5
    if event.is_action_released("forward"):
        speed = 0

func _physics_process(delta):
    direction = direction.rotated(Vector3(0, 1, 0), $Node3D.rotation.y)
    position = position.move_toward(direction, speed * delta)
    move_and_slide()
```

but for some reason it moves down, I don’t know what the problem is. Please, help.
[scene tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0wuw.png)

Comment: Could you share your scene tree? I can't figure out how you've setup things

Comment: @M.R.M. ok, I did it

Comment: why do you have a separate script for the `Camera3D`? I don't think it's a good idea unless the camera de-attaches from the player (which I'm sure isn't the case for you), perhaps try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AW3rT-7J8ag) instead?